# authorization with social network Tornado.auth

Tags: python, authentication, tornado

First, sorry for my bad English. I need to write in the application authorization with social networks using tornado.auth. But I can not understand how the example in the documentation for tornado.auth work, for example for Facebook.

```
Class FacebookGraphLoginHandler (tornado.web.RequestHandler,
                                tornado.auth.FacebookGraphMixin):
  @ tornado.gen.coroutine
  def get (self):
      if self.get_argument ( "code", False):
          user = yield self.get_authenticated_user (
              redirect_uri = '/ auth / facebookgraph /',
              client_id = self.settings [ "facebook_api_key"],
              client_secret = self.settings [ "facebook_secret"],
              code = self.get_argument ( "code"))
          # Save the user with e.g. set_secure_cookie
      else:
          yield self.authorize_redirect (
              redirect_uri = '/ auth / facebookgraph /',
              client_id = self.settings [ "facebook_api_key"],
              extra_params = { "scope": "read_stream, offline_access"})
```

What's 'code'?  In which form data returned from social network? How can i process it? It's would be good, if you explain for Google+ too, because you can only get the access_token from g+, how I understand. Thanks